# Invoking a templated function defined in another translation unit

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, c++20

How can a templated function be invoked, that is defined in another translation unit?

I found so far *solutions* that require explicit instantiation of all used combinations. For  more complex scenarios it is almost impossible to maintain manually. So I wonder if there is a neat way to achieve that **without explicit instantiation**?

A simple scenario could look like this:

```
// a.h

template <typename D> struct base {/*...*/};
struct a : base<a> {/*...*/};
struct b : base<b> {/*...*/};
struct c : base<c> {/*...*/};
```

```
// main.cpp

#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main () {
    DoSomething<a>(1,2,3);
    DoSomething<a>('h','e','l','l','o');
    DoSomething<b>(4,'a',5.0);
    DoSomething<c>('f','o','o',6.0f);
}
```

```
// b.h

// forward declaration
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void DoSomething (Args...);
```

```
// b.cpp

#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void DoSomething (Args... args) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Use case is the launch of a templated CUDA kernel launcher, where `b.h` and `b.cpp` act as CUDA header & definition. CUDA nvcc compiler/linker come with a few more restrictions, that appear to me not to be relevant for the minimal example above (no `auto` keyword, no `module` support), so tried to provide an example as generic as possible.

Comment: You either define the template in the header file, or you have to explicitly instantiate it.  AFAIK those are the only options.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Unfortunately the use of the 2nd translation unit is required, since has to be compiled by another compiler (nvcc).

Comment: The question related to the one marked duplicate is 13 years old - no changes since then?

Comment: No, there have been no changes in this behavior.